# What is the programming flow for Xml Parsing in IPhone?can any one explain?

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

i need to know aboout XML parsing in IPhone.clearly about the programming flow for XML Parsiung in IPHone??

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Parsers.

Ones that scan through the document line by line and provide information about each element it  encounters in sequence. In this you have to map out your own tree-structure of the document. If I remember correctly this is how the default NSXMLParser works.

The other kind reads in the whole document and identifies the XML structure for you. You are then free to step through the document as you please, using something like XPath. Google's GData is an example.

(I will have to double check the examples I gave. I'll edit my post if I am incorrect, or the community will let us know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:

http://buildmobile.com/parsing-xml-files-with-objective-c/#fbid=5_d9J0DpbCv

and this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242493/How-do-XML-Parsing-in-objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Im iphone there are various type of parsing one is NSXmlParsing and Gdata parsing.

for Gdata Parsing 
http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-gdata-to-parse-xml-file.html

and for NSXmlParsing you have to use NSXMLParser ans add some delegate see link below

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242493/How-do-XML-Parsing-in-objective-C